# How to make large font size scale with min. font size from user preferences

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

I have a div set with a font size of `12`, and another div at `24`.

When the user has let's say a min. `font-size` set at `16px`, how do I make the div with `24` scale (x2) with the new `font-size` of `16`?

(I'm actually using em not px so the small div font is set at `.75em`)

Comment: Maybe use rem instead of em?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest solution involves `SASS` where you can store a variable for font-size. Here's an example

```
$fontSize: 14px;
```

You can then reference that value in your css

```
div1 {
  font-size: $fontSize;
}
```

You can also perform arithmetic with SASS variables.

```
div2 {
  font-size: $fontSize * 2;
}
```

If you would like to change the font-size, you can simply change the value of the `$fontSize` variable, and it will update in both selections.

It's also possible to do this through native JavaScript.

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
var button = document.getElementById("my-button");
    
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var minFontSize = Number(prompt("Please enter your minimum font-size"));
    div1.style.fontSize = minFontSize + "px";
    div2.style.fontSize = (minFontSize * 2) + "px";
    div1.style.display = "block";
    div2.style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">This is the first div</div>
<div id="div2">This is the second div</div>

<button id="my-button">Change Font Size</button>
```

Breakdown

First create variables to reference your two divs and a button. These will be given a hidden value at first.

We will then listen for the `click` event, and prompt for a minimum font-size.

We can now set the `font-size` and `display` properties with `object.style.rule` syntax.

Basically, we are scaling the font-sizes through pure JavaScript.

The same can also be done with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-button").on("click", function() {
      var minFontSize = prompt("Please enter a minimum font size");
      $("#div1").css({"display": "block", "font-size": minFontSize + "px"});
      $("#div2").css({"display": "block", "font-size": (minFontSize * 2) + "px"});
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">This is the first div</div>
<div id="div2">
This is the second div
</div>

<button id="my-button">
Change Font Size
</button>
```

It's actually easier using jQuery, because you can add multiple styles with one `css` declaration.